# Why is there a difference in precision range widths for decimal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As is evident by the [MSDN description of decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) certain precision ranges have the same amount of storage bytes assigned to them.

[image: Precision ranges with their respective storage size]

What I don't understand is that there are differences in the sizes of the range. How the range from 1 to 9 of 5 storage bytes has a width of 9, while the range from 10 to 19 of 9 storage bytes has a width of 10. Then the next range of 13 storage bytes has a width of 9 again, while the next has a width of 10 again.

Since the storage bytes increase by 4 every time, I would have expected all of the ranges to be the same width. Or maybe the first one to be smaller to reserve space for the sign or something but from then on equal in width. But it goes from 9 to 10 to 9 to 10 again.

What's going on here? And if it would exist, would 21 storage bytes have a precision range of 39-47 i.e. is the pattern 9-10-9-10-9-10...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would 21 storage bytes have a precision range of 39-47

No. `2 ^ 160 = 1,461,501,637,330,902,918,203,684,832,716,283,019,655,932,542,976` - which has 49 decimal digits. So this hypothetical scenario would cater for a precision range of `39-48` (as a 20 byte integer would not be big enough to hold any 49 digit numbers larger than that)

---

The first byte is reserved for the sign.

`01` is used for positive numbers; `00` for negative.

The remainder stores the value as an integer. i.e. `1.234` would be stored as the integer `1234` (or some multiple of 10 of this dependant on the declared scale)

The length of the integer is either `4`, `8`, `12` or `16`bytes depending on the declared precision. Some `10` digit integers can be stored in `4` bytes however to get the whole range in would overflow this so it needs to go to the next step up.

And so on.

- `2^32 = 4,294,967,295` (10 digits)
- `2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616` (20 digits)
- `2^96 = 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336` (29 digits)
- `2^128 = 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456` (39 digits)

You need to use `DBCC PAGE` to see this, casting the column as `binary` does not give you the storage representation. Or use a utility like SQL Server internals viewer.

```
   CREATE TABLE T(
   A DECIMAL( 9,0), 
   B DECIMAL(19,0),
   C DECIMAL(28,0)  ,
   D DECIMAL(38,0) 
   );

   INSERT INTO T VALUES
   (999999999, 9999999999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999999, 99999999999999999999999999999999999999),
   (-999999999, -9999999999999999999, -9999999999999999999999999999, -99999999999999999999999999999999999999);
```

Shows the first row stored as

[image]

And the second as

[image]

Note that the values after the sign bit are byte reversed. `0x3B9AC9FF` = `999999999`

Comment: The representation in `BINARY` form is quite interesting -- it's precision and scale as bytes, then the sign as a 16-bit value, followed by the bytes that make up the digits, but only as many as necessary to represent the value, rounded to the nearest multiple of 4 to pad it out. This results in something that's sometimes smaller, sometimes larger than the on-disk representation (and altogether more suitable for processing in memory, of course).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I'm not sure what the third byte (between the scale and the sign bytes) is used for. [This indicates that it might be for the length](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDecimal.cs) but always seems to be 0 for me. Maybe just padding to 4 bytes

Comment: Good of you to check! It's always 0 when explicitly converting to `BINARY`, but I guess this may be masked off before being presented. Internally it would make sense that the length is included (otherwise the engine would have no way of knowing it). Of course technically `SqlDecimal` does not have to precisely match the engine's format (which is in turn not the same as the on-the-wire representation in TDS), but it's highly likely that it does -- I think a lot of this is engine code "translated" to C# for fidelity.

Comment: Worth noting is that values for this byte are not preserved on conversion -- `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 1), 0x0901AA010A000000))` is `0x090100010A000000`. This further strengthens my conviction that this is in fact the length, but masked off by the engine because it's redundant when stored in a column or variable. Replacing this byte with 0 is faster/easier than converting from/to a byte sequence where this byte is removed from the middle.